# How do I extract text from a web page with <br /> tags using Hpricot?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

I'm trying to parse an HTML file using Hpricot and Ruby, but I'm having issues extracting "free floating" text which is not enclosed in tags like `<p></p>`.

```
require 'hpricot'

text = <<SOME_TEXT
  <a href="http://www.somelink.com/foo/bar.html">Testing:</a><br />
  line 1<br />  
  line 2<br />
  line 3<br />
  line 4<br />
  line 5<br />
  <b>Here's some more text</b>
SOME_TEXT

parsed = Hpricot(text)

parsed = parsed.search('//a[@href="http://www.somelink.com/foo/bar.html"]').first.following_siblings
puts parsed
```

I would expect the result to be

```
<br />
line 1<br />  
line 2<br />
line 3<br />
line 4<br />
line 5<br />
<b>Here's some more text</b>
```

But I am getting

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<b>Here's some more text</b>
```

How can I make Hpricot return line 1, line 2, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is to read the [following_siblings](http://rubydoc.info/gems/hpricot/0.8.3/Hpricot/Container/Trav%3afollowing_siblings) documentation:

> Find sibling elements which follow the current one. Like the other “sibling” methods, this **weeds out text and comment nodes**.

Then you should use the Hpricot source to generalize how `following_siblings` works to get something that works like `following_siblings` but doesn't filter out non-container nodes:

```
parsed        = Hpricot(text)
link          = parsed.search('//a[@href="http://www.somelink.com/foo/bar.html"]').first
link_sibs     = link.parent.children
what_you_want = link_sibs[link_sibs.index(link) + 1 ... link_sibs.length]

puts what_you_want
```

That's pretty much `following_siblings` with `parent.children` instead of `parent.containers`. Having access to the source code of the libraries you use is pretty handy and studying it is to be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Hpricot but here's some things I remember that might help:

The quick way to get all the text:

```
irb(main):023:0> print parsed.inner_text
  Testing:
  line 1  
  line 2
  line 3
  line 4
  line 5
  Here's some more text
```

The downside to that is you get the text embedded in tags too.

Similarly, we can search for all `'text()'` nodes:

```
irb(main):033:0> puts (parsed / 'text()')

Testing:

  line 1

  [...]

  line 5
```

So, we can do this:

```
irb(main):036:0> puts (parsed / 'text()')[2 .. -3]

  line 1

  line 2

  line 3

  line 4

  line 5
```

or:

```
irb(main):037:0> (parsed / 'text()')[2 .. -3]
=> #<Hpricot::Elements["\n  line 1", "  \n  line 2", "\n  line 3", "\n  line 4", "\n  line 5", "\n  "]>
```

or:

```
irb(main):039:0> (parsed / 'text()')[2 .. -3].map{ |t| t.inner_text.strip }
=> ["line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5", ""]
```

The main idea for grabbing data/text from a web page is look for landmarks you can use to navigate through the page. Often we can grab text from inside a `<div>` or `<p>` tag. If a page doesn't give you landmarks you have to use other tricks; Looking for a series of text nodes followed by `<br>` nodes maybe, or the five lines following an `<a>` tag with a certain `href` attribute. That's the fun and challenge of dealing with HTML.

In the back of my mind there's a nagging thought that there is a more elegant way to do this, but this seems to be working. Dig around on the [Hpricot Challenge page](https://github.com/whymirror/hpricot/wiki/Hpricot-Challenge) for variations on themes on digging out content.